# Ubuntu 14.04 Openstack single, error: Top-level container OS did not initialize correctly

Tags: 14.04, openstack

I install fresh copy of Ubuntu server 14.04 x64 on my laptop ram:16GB, i7 quadcore, ssd:1TB. etc.
I follow this instruction to install openstack as single on my laptop

1. ubuntu user have sudo privileges,
2. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cloud-installer/stable`
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo apt-get upgrade`
5. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
6. `sudo apt-get install openstack`
7. `sudo openstack-install`
8. I choose single
9. I get error: Top-level container OS did not initialize correctly

Can someone help me to install openstack on ubuntu server 14.04.5 in single?

Thanks.